# Is there a way to take a screenshot in KDE desktop by pressing only the "PrtSc" key?

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, print-screen

I am using Fedora 25. I have installed both GNOME and KDE and some other desktop systems. I frequently take screenshots when I see any video like tutorial, documentary etc.

For GNOME to take a screenshot I can simply press the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> button and there is no extra work to save it. But in KDE, after pressing  <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> I have to save it. Across many screenshots this is  annoying and also takes time; however, I do like the UI of KDE.

So is there any way that I could take a screenshot like GNOME, without going through the additional process of saving the image, in KDE?

If currently there is no such option or program to do that, is it possible to make a program to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Shift + PrtSc works for me. To change the shortcut key, have to check the hotkeys.

For newer versions of Plasma, the screenshot shortcut settings are under Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts. The screenshot below is for an older version.

[image]

Comment: I do not have much of entries under "KDE daemon" in this menu. What KDE version do you use? What distro?

Comment: Black Swan is, I believe, using a fairly old version of KDE. New versions of KDE doesn't have those all those shortcuts under the KDE Daemon tab.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

- Install spectacle.
- Run Spectacle (required to initialize the keybindings).
- Select modify -> shortcuts.
- Disable PrtSc as the shortcut to run Spectacle.
- Reassign PrtSc as the shortcut to take an image of the current screen.

Comment: I confirm that this method is working. Thanks.